# Deleting with DataSet

Tags: c#, ado.net, delete-row, sqldataadapter

I'm wondering regardin delete line `ds.Tables[0].Rows[1].Delete();`in sample below. I suppose that during this second row deletions delete command was used with script  `"DELETE FROM Person WHERE PersonId = @PersonId"`  and parameter `@PersonId`. But what was passed to `@PersonId` parameter? According to my understanding statement `ds.Tables[0].Rows[1].Delete()` means delete second row of `table[0]`, why do it needs `@PersonId`at all?

```
static void DataSetUpdateDelete()
{
    SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection();
    cn.ConnectionString = "Server = GM\\SQLEXPRESS; Database = Reflection; Trusted_Connection = True;";
    cn.Open();

    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM Person", cn);

    //Create the update command
    SqlCommand update = new SqlCommand();
    update.Connection = cn;
    update.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    update.CommandText = "UPDATE Person SET FirstName = @FirstName, LastName = @LastName WHERE PersonId = @PersonId";

    //Create the parameters
    update.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@FirstName", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50, "FirstName"));
    update.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@LastName", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50, "LastName"));
    update.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@PersonId", SqlDbType.Int, 0, "PersonId"));

    //Create the delete command
    SqlCommand delete = new SqlCommand();
    delete.Connection = cn;
    delete.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    delete.CommandText = "DELETE FROM Person WHERE PersonId = @PersonId";

    //Create the parameters
    SqlParameter deleteParameter = new SqlParameter("@PersonId", SqlDbType.Int, 0, "PersonId");
    deleteParameter.SourceVersion = DataRowVersion.Original;
    delete.Parameters.Add(deleteParameter);

    //Associate the update and delete commands with the DataAdapter.
    da.UpdateCommand = update;
    da.DeleteCommand = delete;

    //Get the data.
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    da.Fill(ds, "Person");

    //Update the first row
    ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["FirstName"] = "Jack";
    ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["LastName"] = "Johnson";

    //Delete the second row.
    ds.Tables[0].Rows[1].Delete();

    //Updat the database.
    da.Update(ds.Tables[0]);

    cn.Close();
}
```

Comment: I suggest you look at some DataSet / DataAdapter tutorials.  When you call `ds.Tables[0].Rows[1].Delete()` the row in the DataSet is marked as deleted.  Similarly inserts and updates are marked as such.  Then you can call `DataAdapter.Update`, which will go through all changed rows in your DataTable, and (as the documentation says) "Calls the respective INSERT, UPDATE, or DELETE statements for each inserted, updated, or deleted row in the specified DataSet …".  This will push your changes to the database, and to push a Delete, it needs `@PersonId` to know which database row to delete.

Comment: So, some internals will pass value to `@PersonId` taken from `Tables[0].Rows[1] field  "PersonId" ` and will execute script. My job is to write clever script that will recognize correct record to delete. In this case `PersonId` is not good solution since I can have several records with same PersonId's

Comment: The WHERE clause in the UPDATE and DELETE statements will generally reference the table's primary key column(s).  If PersonId isn't the primary key, you need to rewrite your UPDATE and DELETE statements accordingly.